# I got Error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in drupal

Tags: drupal

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded on line 171 in Drupal.

I am new in the world of drupal My port no.80 is assigned to my ASP server so I changed my Apache server from 80 to 8080 in httpd.conf , BTW I am using XAMPP server I got Error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyDemoWebsite\core\modules\mysql\src\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection.php on line 171" while install site after Set up database in core instal

[Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CIEI.png)

May be I am doing somthing wrong in Set Up Database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfEos.png)   I have tried by changing the port no. to 8080[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFOvO.png)